# How to make Strapi recognize custom domain pointing to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, strapi

I'm using an S3 bucket to store static assets through the **strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3** plugin. Also, I have a custom domain pointing to that bucket via SSL. Basically, *https://my.domain.com/photo.jpg* points to *https://s3.amazonaws.com/my.domain.com/photo.jpg*. Is there any way to let the plugin know this so it automatically changes the URLs from *s3.amazonaws.com/my.domain.com* to just *my.domain.com* before updating the field containing such a URL?

If this isn't possible via a straightforward configuration or the dashboard, is there any way to tweak the code itself to incorporate this functionality? And if so (am strongly hoping there is), what file holds this logic should one were to go this route?

Comment: Relative vs Absolute URL in your code might fix it. Use relative URLs in your code. You don’t have code to review, so it’s tough to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case the best way is to update the plugin upload itself (./plugins/upload).
There is currently no customisation for your need.

To do so you will have to update the `findAll` function and replace the host manually in the `map` before sending the data.

Here is the code I speak about: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-upload/controllers/Upload.js#L122

You will have to replace the url to match with your need.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, but after a lot of hours of research, you can do the next:

First configure an S3 bucket with the name of your custom domain for example: `static.yourdomain.com` and make it as Static Hosting on S3 Settings, after in your configuration of strapi S3 provider put the next:

```
providerOptions: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || '',
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET || '',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      endpoint: 'static.yourdomain.com',
      s3BucketEndpoint: true,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'static.yourdomain.com'
      },
    }
```

In your DNS create an CNAME `static.yourdomain.com` which points to the s3 public domain, but the trick is the following:

Instead of this:

```
static.yourdomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Put this:

```
static.yourdomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```